# How can I render a set of primitives using Avalonia and Skia backend on macos?

Tags: macos, .net-core, skiasharp, skia, avaloniaui

I need to create a simple app to draw a graph network onto a canvas. As I use .net core it seems that one of the best solutions could be Avalonia + Skia backend. The problem is that I haven't found any good documentation or example showing it.

How could I render a set of primites using Avalonia and Skia render backend?

Comment: I would also be curious. But according to this video Avalonia+Direct2D has the best performance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP1RMn8CixY